# Set the order in which form controls are looped through

Tags: vb.net, foreach

I'm looping through all of the controls on a certain Tab Page and the grabbing the `.tag` property for some further actions from checkboxes that are `checked`.

However, I require these controls to be looped in a certain order (I was hoping they'd be ordered by `tab index`), but it appears that they are not.

Is there any way to force the order that they are looped? Thanks.

```
Dim objCtrl As Control
For Each objCtrl In Me.objConfigForm.tabPageGeneral.Controls

    If TypeOf objCtrl Is CheckBox AndAlso DirectCast(objCtrl, CheckBox).Checked Then

        Dim strProp As String = DirectCast(objCtrl, CheckBox).Tag
        Dim strListItem As String = CallByName(objUser, strProp, CallType.Get)
        lstGeneral.Add(strListItem)

    End If

Next
```

Comment: You do know that the [.Net Style guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx) now specifically recommend **against** prefixes like `str` and `obj`, right?

Comment: I did not, but I'll take that under advisement for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.OrderBy()` extension to choose an order. Also, while we're at it, you can replace the `If` block with `Where()` and `OfType()` extensions to reduce nesting and casting:

```
For Each box As CheckBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)() _
                         .Where(Function(b) b.Checked) _
                         .OrderBy(Function(b) b.TabIndex)

    lstGeneral.Add(CallByName(objUser, box.Tag, CallType.Get))
Next
```

---

Update: this is a bit old, but it came back into my feed today, so it's still indexed by Google somewhere. With that in mind, today I'd write the code like this instead:

```
Dim selectedCheckboxNames = Me.Controls.
        OfType(Of CheckBox)().
        Where(Function(b) b.Checked).
        OrderBy(Function(b) b.TabIndex).
        Select(Function(b) CallByName(objUser, b.Tag, CallType.Get))
lstGeneral.AddRange(selectedCheckboxNames)
```

One of the important change is introducing a variable for the result of the linq query. This can sometimes add valuable insight to code for future developers, and it always helps make the `For Each` loop easier to read... assuming you haven't also been able to convert to an `AddRange()`, as I've done here. I'm also more comfortable now taking advantage of implicit line continuations and `Option Infer`.

Comment: Wouldn't I want `Me.objConfigForm.tabPageGeneral.Controls.OfType()` to get just the relevant controls? Also, I'm getting an error `'OfType' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Form.Control.ControlCollection'`. Thanks.

Comment: With the help of @KarlAnderson I found out that I need to add `Imports System.Linq` to the Class, and now your code works. It's simple and elegant, and I'm going to use your answer, so thanks muchly.

Answer (score 4):

Use LINQ to sort the controls by `TabIndex`, like this:

```
For Each objCtrl As Control In Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control).OrderBy(Function(c) c.TabIndex)
    If TypeOf objCtrl Is CheckBox AndAlso DirectCast(objCtrl, CheckBox).Checked Then
        Dim strProp As String = DirectCast(objCtrl, CheckBox).Tag
        Dim strListItem As String = CallByName(objUser, strProp, CallType.Get)
        lstGeneral.Add(strListItem)
    End If
Next
```

---

> Note: The above code requires the `System.Linq` namespace be imported into your code file to support the `Cast()` and `OrderBy()` LINQ extension methods.

Comment: Thanks, but this is giving me the error `'Cast' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Form.Control.ControlCollection'` (pretty much the same as the error generated by the example from @JoelCoehoorn). Is there an import I'm missing?

Comment: @DavidGard - yes, `Cast()` is a LINQ extension method so you need to have the `System.Linq` namespace imported.

Comment: Ah ha, perfect. Thanks for the help, that's done the job. I hope you don't think me rude though, but I've accepted another answer as I've ended up using that one, which also required the import. I wish I could say you were both correct!

Comment: @DavidGard - no worries about you breaking my heart and picking another answer (just kidding), all that matters is that you got it working, sorry about the confusion. Good luck to you. :-)